# Running Object Table

Tags: vb.net, matlab, com

I'm trying to use several Matlab COM object in order to parallelize computations (i'm not really limited in license tokens).

Because of I don't know why, the progids linked to the GUIDs aren't specified on the installations (as "Matlab.Application") so the GetObject() method returns nothing.

So in order to retrieve a COM object I usually use the Running Object Table (ROT) and retrieve the first one found.

This time I try to retrieve more than one COM object, with the following function :

```vb
Private Function GetCOMFromTable(Of T)() As List(Of T)

    Try
        Dim ReturnCOMList As New List(Of T)
        Dim RunningObjectTable As IRunningObjectTable
        Dim MonikerEnumerator As IEnumMoniker = Nothing
        Dim Monikers(1) As IMoniker

        RunningObjectTable = GetRunningObjectTable(0)
        RunningObjectTable.EnumRunning(MonikerEnumerator)
        MonikerEnumerator.Reset()

        Dim NumFetched As New IntPtr()
        While MonikerEnumerator.Next(1, Monikers, NumFetched) = 0
            Dim RunningObjectIns As Object = Nothing
            RunningObjectTable.GetObject(Monikers(0), RunningObjectIns)
            If TypeOf RunningObjectIns Is T Then ReturnCOMList.Add(DirectCast(RunningObjectIns, T))
        End While

        Return ReturnCOMList

    Catch Exc As Exception
        Throw Exc
    End Try

End Function
```

Here is my problem :

For each Matlab process started, three COM object are registered in the ROT.
So I assumed that they were the same COM object registered three times.

So, say if I need three Matlab, I start three Matlab process and retrieve nine COM object. In order to keep only three of them, I use the following function :

```vb
Private Function SelectMatlabs(ByRef Matlabs As List(Of DIMLApp)) As List(Of DIMLApp)

    Dim SelectedMatlabs As New List(Of DIMLApp)
    Dim SelectingHashet As New HashSet(Of Integer)
    For i = 1 To Matlabs.Count
        Matlabs(i - 1).Execute("a=" & i)
    Next
    For Each Matlab In Matlabs
        If SelectingHashet.Add(Matlab.GetVariable("a", "base")) Then SelectedMatlabs.Add(Matlab)
    Next

    Return SelectedMatlabs

End Function
```

But this function only retrieve one COM object. The first one of the list. 
When I manually try to retrieve the variable 'a' in Matlab, only the first executed knows it, and it returns 9.

It seems that all the nine COM object are linked to the first Matlab process started.

Is it the expected behaviour ? Is there something wrong in the way to iterate through the objects in the ROT ?

Thanks,

Comment: I think your problem has nothing to do with running object table behaviour since nowadays I am using the same method to handle multiple com objects (IBM Rhapsody COM Interface especially) and it works as I expected.